# Slack Bot to see all Direct Message Channels

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I am trying to implement a Bot which can get all the Direct Message Channels, all the workspace Users and send Direct Messages to them.
If I work with my development workspace everything works as expected but when I try with my company workspace, my Bot is only capable to retrieve the Direct Message Channel it is belonging to.
Any idea on how to fix by production Bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Slack support I got my answer:

> The OAuth Token issued is specific to the user who has installed your app and represents the permission(s) to perform actions on behalf of the user. More detailed information here - https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth.
>   The token can only perform the same actions as the user who installed the app i.e If the user can’t view or post in the channel, they can’t grant permission to something they do not have.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Due to the security architecture of Slack one can only see the messages of channels he is part of. Its the same even for the "super admin" of a Slack team (the primary owner). Bots and apps inherit that right from the user who installed it (= authed the access token).

The reason it works on your development Slack, is that your user has probably created all private channels on Slack, and/or is the same that authed the access token your app uses.

Comment: Based on what you said I have created 2 new Users and with the first one I invited the second one. Also the second one's direct message channel is visible by the Bot.

Comment: And by the way what is the point of allowing Bots to retrieve direct message channels if they are just allowed to see their own one?

Comment: hmm... I strongly doubt that a bot which has been installed by a user A, can see the direct message channel between user B and user C, which he is not part of.